# Data extraction from webpage by beatifulsoup python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hello everyone，I'm doing a python script which need extract data from a website and store the date into sqlite3.  I got a problem in contents extration. here's the code I did

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

url="http://m.harveynorman.com.au/tv-audio/portable-audio/ipods"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
A=soup.findAll('strong',{'class':'name fn'})
for B in A:

   print = B.renderContents()
```

and the output is like that:

```
 "iPod touch 16GB - White   
   iPod touch 4th Gen 32GB  
 Apple iPod Shuffle 2GB  
 iPod touch 16GB - Black  
 iPod nano 16GB  
  iPod touch 32GB"
```

and I try to use

```
   print = B.renderContents()[0]
```

to get the specify one to insert into sqlite3, but the output is like that:

```
i 
i
A
i
i
i
```

So my question is how can I extract the specify one (like : iPod touch 16GB - White)???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

url="http://m.harveynorman.com.au/tv-audio/portable-audio/ipods"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
A = soup.findAll('strong',{'class':'name fn'})[0]
print(A.renderContents())
```

yields

```
iPod touch 16GB - White
```

---

```
for B in A:
    print B.renderContents()[0]
```

is printing the first *character* of each line of

```
iPod touch 16GB - White
iPod touch 4th Gen 32GB
Apple iPod Shuffle 2GB
iPod touch 16GB - Black
iPod nano 16GB
iPod touch 32GB
```